# ifelse statement within a data.table query in R

Tags: r, if-statement, data.table

I have an issue with conditional statement in data.table.

My DF is made of different dates associated with different ids. And I want to get the max date for each id. But:

**EDIT**: Here is the DF, sorry:

```
df <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,5,5,5,5),
                 date=c("2016-01-21", "2016-01-13", NA, "2016-01-13",
                        "2016-01-13", "2016-01-13", "2016-02-02", "2016-01-25", NA,
                        "2016-01-25", "2016-01-25", "2016-01-25", "2016-01-25"))
```

If I don't include the ifelse fonction, data.table gives me a warning because of the single NA for ID 4 which as been removed during the process

```
agg <- setDT(df)[,
                 .SD[,
                     .(max_date=max(as.Date(date), na.rm=TRUE))
                     ],
                 by=.(id)
                 ]
```

> Warning message: In max.default(NA_real_, na.rm = TRUE) :   no
>   non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf

This warning appears explicitly in the documentation of `?max`

> For min and max if there are only numeric inputs and all are empty
>   (after possible removal of NAs), the result is double (Inf or -Inf).

If I handle this problem with a condition, I get an error:

```
agg <- setDT(df)[,
                 .SD[,
                     .(max_date=ifelse(
                        (is.na(as.Date(date)) & .N == 1),
                        max(as.Date(date), na.rm=TRUE),
                        NA))
                     ],
                 by=.(id)
                 ]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(setDT(df), , .SD[, .(max_date =
>   ifelse((is.na(as.Date(date)) &  :    Column 1 of result for group 4 is
>   type 'double' but expecting type 'logical'. Column types must be
>   consistent for each group. In addition: Warning message: In
>   max.default(NA_real_, na.rm = TRUE) :   no non-missing arguments to
>   max; returning -Inf

So my question is double:

- I don't understand the later error from data.table
- How can I include an ifelse statement in data.table when it comes to assigning a value to a new variable (given that I want to store the result in another DT, no modification by reference.)

Thanks

Comment: 1- You don't need `.SD` here at all. 2- better use `as.IDate` for integer storage mode. 3- Don't convert to `Date` per group, rather only once. 4- Specify `NA_integer_` instead of just `NA`. 5- this isn't reproducible so hard to tell really.

Comment: And if you want to avoid the warning (which is useful IMO) you could try `setDT(df)[, date := as.IDate(date)]` (this will convert the whole column to `IDate` class at once) and then using a simple `if` statement  `df[, if(all(is.na(date))) NA_integer_ else max(date, na.rm = TRUE), by = id]`

Comment: I added a reproductible example. I admit, I didn't really understand how to use .SD. Isn't it for working on a subset of the DT. Like "take the max of the DT inside the subset by id?"

Comment: Safer is `df[, if (all(is.na(date))) date[1L] else max(date, na.rm=TRUE), by=id]` @DavidA, so it still gives a date-class col even if the first group is all NA

Comment: @Frank good point.

Comment: @David, the the assignment by reference `:=` modify the original DT? I ant to store the result in another DT without modifying the original one.

Comment: @Synleb use `.SD` only if you want to return the *whole* subset instead of a certain column. *Or* if you are using `.SDcols` and specifying certain columns to operate on. Then you could use stuff like `lapply(.SD, ..` etc.

Comment: @Synleb Why would you want a date column not of a `Date` class? How is it going to be of any use to you?

Comment: Ok you have edited your post. Thanks

Comment: @Frank can you explain what date[1L] means? it gives the same result as  the solution provided by David but it is less clear to me.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it means "select the first element". It's the same as `date[1]` but uses the integer version of `1`, which is indicated by an `L`. As for the reason, consider `DT = data.table(a = 1:2, b = as.IDate(Sys.Date())[2:1])`. If you do `DT[, if (all(is.na(b))) NA_integer_ else max(b), by=a]`, you see weird results; but it works fine if you replace NA_integer_ with b[1] or even b[NA_integer_]. The goal is just to get an NA of class "Date" or "IDate"